# formidable image upload error

Tags: node.js, formidable

When I upload an image under 1 MB then it will be fine and uploaded to server but when I exceed the size of image to UP e.g. 2 MB then it says **"413 Request Entity Too Large"** how we can change maximum upload size of node js or formidable ?
I googled it but nothing found.

Comment: are you running a webserver on top of nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

Install bodyParser `npm install --save bodyParser`  and do

```
   var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
   app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '5mb'}));
   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '5mb', extended: true}));
```

make sure in formidable options maxFieldsSize is set above 2mb, lets say 5mb
   `form.maxFieldsSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;`